# How to modify bullets?

Tags: html, vba, outlook

How do I format the bullet point itself?

The bullet points all appear as stars instead of a normal black circle for the first bullet and a hollow circle for the sub-bullet.

I tried to define the style but my code gives me an error message when I add `list-style-type:disc;`.

Using w3schools this is how I understand it should work.

```
Sub Email_Budget()
   
   Dim objOutlook As Object
   Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   
   Dim objEmail As Object
   Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   
   Dim CaseCount As Long
   CaseCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B6:B500"))
   Debug.Print CaseCount
   
   Dim i As Integer
   
   With objEmail
      .To = "abc@xyz.com"
      .Subject = "TEST1: May 2019 Budget"
      .Body = "Kurt,"
      .Body = .Body & " "
      .Body = .Body & "The potential " & MonthName(Month(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"))) & " invoices are below."
      .Body = .Body & " "
      For i = 1 To CaseCount
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 4).Value = "Yes" Then
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<ul style='list-style-type:disc;'>" & "<li>" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 2).Value & " - " & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 6).Value, "Currency") & " (" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 8).Value, "Currency") & " without budget or invoicing)." & "</li>" & "<ul>" & "<li>" & "Last billed " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 10) & "." & "</li>" & "</ul>" & "</ul>"
        End If
      Next i
      .Body = .Body & " "
      .Body = .Body & " "
      .Body = .Body & "Thank you,"
      .Body = .Body & "Karen"
      .Display
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to build another `<ul>` nested beneath one of your `<li>` items. You can tinker with HTML here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3UBZA6VM2WS

Comment: Pure HTML approach you can use the `li type` (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_type.asp) or configure the `ul` element's `style` attribute like: `<ul style="list-style-type:circle;">`.

Comment: Perfect - thank you!  Any advice for formatting the bullet points themselves?

Comment: If you poke around w3 you'll find that information as well. Though it might ultimately be easier to create an empty email and then edit it via its [`WordEditor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor), that way you have full access to all of the defined styles & formatting in MS Word, rather than trying to conjure up the raw HTML from scratch.

Comment: Thank you everyone, much appreciated!

Comment: I updated my question above - we're almost there. Thanks again.

Comment: Is the error that the code won't compile? it looks like you've got mismatched quotes. Since the HTML *is* a string literal, and a set of double-quotes marks the beginning & end of a string, you can't *also* use double-quotes *within* the HTML, unless you escape them. Or, I think you can also use single-quote within the string, like: `"<ul style='list-style-type:disc;'>"`

Comment: When I run the code using apostrophes instead of quotation marks, the macro works and doesn't display an error message.  However, the bullet points are still stars, not circles, even though I have the definition in the first <> to be "<ul style='list-style-type:disc;'>".

Comment: Can you provide more of your code so that I can see fully what you're doing? It's best to provide a [mcve]. I don't think the problem relates to this single line of code (whether I specify the list-style-type property or not, the bullets for me are the "disc" style, so this would seem to be the default style -- I don't even see "star" as one of the options in Outlook)

Comment: Yes of course, I've updated the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create multi-level list, you can simply construct another `<ul>` nested beneath one of your `<li>` items. You can tinker with HTML here:

http://w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3UBZA6VM2WS

To control the list item style for an individual `<li>` item, specify it's [`type` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_type.asp)`.

To set the list item style for *all* items in a list, specify the [`style` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ul_type.asp) with the appropriate css, e.g.:

```
"<ul style='list-style-type:disc'>"
```

Note the use of single-quotes within the quoted string :)

Finally, and I now suspect that this was your problem all along (disc style appears to be the default in Outlook, so you probably don't need to *specify* it as such):

You can't mix `.Body` and `.HTMLBody`. You need to use one or the other. If you use `.Body`, the email will be plain text and will **not** accept or render HTML. So you should convert all of your `.Body` assignments to the appropriate `.HTMLBody` instead. Untested, but should be something like this:

```
With objEmail
    .To = "abc@xyz.com"
    .Subject = "TEST1: May 2019 Budget"
    .HTMLBody = "Kurt,"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<p>The potential " & MonthName(Month(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"))) & " invoices are below.</p>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>"
    For i = 1 To CaseCount
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 4).Value = "Yes" Then
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<ul style='list-style-type:disc;'>" & "<li>" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 2).Value & " - " & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 6).Value, "Currency") & " (" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 8).Value, "Currency") & " without budget or invoicing)." & "</li>" & "<ul>" & "<li>" & "Last billed " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 10) & "." & "</li>" & "</ul>" & "</ul>"
        End If
    Next i
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><br>"
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<p>" & "Thank you," & "</p>" 
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<p>" & "Karen" & "</p>" 
    .Display
End With
```